# How to print the add, mul, sub functions?

Tags: python

I am doing this:

```
        opers = (add, sub, mul)
        rand_choice = random.choice(opers)
        num1 = random.randint(1, operand_level)
        num2 = random.randint(1, operand_level)
        prod = rand_choice(num1, num2)
```

And I would like to print whether the problem is sub, add or mul 
So

```
       print "what is" " rand_choice (num1 ,num2 )
```

Comment: what you want to do ? why you replace rand_choice?

Comment: not sure if I understood what you want... try `print("what is", num1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to post an example that can be run without modification.  The following lines were needed to make the example work:

```
from operator import add,sub,mul
import random
operand_level = 10
```

To print the operator, add the symbol to the list of choices:

```
opers = ('+',add),('-',sub),('x',mul)
symbol,function = random.choice(opers)
num1 = random.randint(1, operand_level)
num2 = random.randint(1, operand_level)
result = function(num1, num2)
print("what is {}{}{}? [{}]".format(num1,symbol,num2,result))
```

Output from multiple runs:

```
what is 1x9? [9]
what is 7-5? [2]
what is 9-4? [5]
what is 10+4? [14]
```

Comment: Thanks! And next time I will definitely paste all of my code so it can run without modification

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via the `__name__` attribute, so:

```
print('what is {}({}, {})'.format(rand_choice.__name__, num1, num2))
```